# Jquery and css not working after ajax call with setTimeout function

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, codeigniter

I've to load data on every 5 seconds. Below code is working on time periods. But Css and Jquery not working.
Thnaks in advance.

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {reload();});
    function reload(){
        console.log('11');
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard/load_data/",
            type: 'post',
            success: function (data) {
               $('#reload_dashboard').html(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
         setTimeout(reload, 5000); 
    }
  }
)();
```

Comment: try this on $(window).load() instead of document.ready()

Comment: What is not working in this code. Specify it.

Comment: @RohanKumar After ajax request call and data append to div css and jquery not work on the appended code.

Comment: So show us that css and jquery part which is not working.

Comment: @RohanKumar Bootstrap  table css and jquery not applying on table

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

`$(doucment).ready(function(){});`

Use this

```
$(window).load(function () {    

});
```